Shopify GraphQL get gift card masked code in order where gift card was purchased
When I retrieve an order that includes a gift cards as the purchased product, I am looking for a way to get the last four characters of the gift card code for accounting purposes – the field is named maskedCode or masked_code.
Via the REST API I could find them in the fulfillment receipt. But with the new GraphQL API I'm a bit lost, where to get this information.
